# go-swagger - swagger serve command not found

Tags: go, swagger, go-swagger

I'm trying to serve a swagger.json file with the command `swagger serve` but I get the error

```
Unknown command `serve'. Please specify one command of: generate, init, validate or version
```

Where is the documentation getting the serve command from?

Comment: go-swagger has no `server` command

Answer (score 1):

what's the version you're on? serve was added in the 0.7.x series so you may have to update your binary.

Comment: I installed it with brew. I am on 0.6.0 with brew but when I check using swagger, I am on 0.5.0

Comment: $ brew upgrade go-swagger                                                                                
`Error: go-swagger/go-swagger/go-swagger 0.6.0 already installed`
$ swagger version                                                                                        
`0.5.0-171-gae8082b`

Comment: is swagger 0.7.0 compatible with go version 1.5.3?

Comment: we support the last 2 versions of go, so no 1.5 sorry.
There should be a 0.7.x version of swagger in brew at this stage. It should be as compatible as 0.6.x for go versions though.